# Changing data-position in jQuery Mobile Dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a header item in my jQuery Mobile layout...

```
 <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" class="textHeader">
 <h3>My Text</h3>
 </div>
```

...that is NOT set to be data-position=fixed. It is set to display and scroll off the screen when the user scrolls down.

However, I want it to become fixed when the orientation of the phone/device is changed to landscape. So I test for the orientation and attempt to change the attribute:

```
$(window).resize(function() { resizeCanvas() });


function resizeCanvas() {

    if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) //portrait
    {

        $(".textHeader").attr("data-position","inline");


    }

    else //landscape
    { 

            $(".textHeader").attr("data-position", "fixed");
    }
 }
```

However, this doesn't work.

What seems to happen is that the header displays as the page loads. Meaning, if I test it and load it on a landscape browser, it behaves fixed all the time; but if I do it portrait, it remains not-fixed all the time.  One thing I am considering is that I need the equivalent of like how you can do a .listview('refresh'), but for a header.

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Comment: In first place the right way to do this is to listen for the jQuery Mobile event "orientationchange". Moreover, you probably want to run .trigger('create') on your page.

Comment: I did consider the jQuery Mobile event "orientationchange," but thought I read somewhere that there was less support for it on certain devices. Is it pretty safe to use?

Comment: Recreating the page is throwing the following error: 
     TypeError: c[0] is undefined


     ..."ui-collapsible-collapsed",k),i.toggleClass("ui-collapsible-content-collapsed",k...

     jquery....min.js (line 2)